# MS Access Run Multiple Queries

Tags: ms-access

I have eight 'append' queries in MS Access 2010 that I want to be able to run. 
Each query also needs to take one parameter (a project number).

I want to run all eight, entering the parameter only once.

I haven't programmed in MS Access before. There are a lot of posts out there.

Do I need to learn how to create a Macro/ a Routine/ a Sub Routine? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Thats off-topic for this forum. The other posts are where you want to look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568461/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-programmatically-in-a-microsoft-access-update

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to learn how to create a Macro/ a Routine/ a Sub Routine?

Yes. See the Stack Overflow question below for an example of how to do it using VBA code and `QueryDef` objects.

[Is it possible to pass parameters programmatically in a Microsoft Access update query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16568461/2144390)

If you require further assistance please as a new question on Stack Overflow.